# Determine the Height and the Width of a BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob, oracle12c

I realized that the images files of the some people are directed landscape, whereas all of them should be portrait, in our database. *So, I need to determine which file has width more than its height.*

I wonder if there is any method to get the `height` and `width` of  `BLOB` type columns such like `dbms_lob.getlength` function which returns the number of characters (bytes) in the `CLOB`/`BLOB` column.

Comment: I would assume that every image format ([JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)) has some kind of header information storing the type and resolution of the image. You would need to extract the header bytes and then interpret that  information yourself. Or try to extract the [exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) information from the header (but not every image has EXIF information)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `BLOB` is binary data - it does not intrinsically have a format (such as JPEG/PNG/BMP) and as such is not implicitly an image and asking what its width/height is does not make sense.

What you need to do is take the binary data (a BLOB) to from its (unknown) binary format (i.e. JPG/PNG/BMP/etc.) and use an Image reader to read the dimensions from the file's meta-data (so you don't have to load the entire file).

You could write a Java class that has a function that takes a BLOB/binary stream and the image format and then uses [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) or [ImageReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) & [ImageInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html) (for example, as the first hits I found on reading images from binary data; there will be other solutions/libraries) extract the dimensions from the header [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12164026/1509264), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16115851/1509264)] and return it.

Then, to load that class into the Oracle database, use the [`loadjava` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html) or `CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845705/1509264) for uncompressing zipped strings stored in an Oracle BLOB).

Then write an SQL function to wrap the Java implementation so that it passes the BLOB to the Java function and returns the width or the height (or a struct containing both values).

---

**Java Code**:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageInputStream;

public class ImageMetaDataReader {
    public static Integer getHeight(
            final Blob   blob,
            final String fileType
    ) throws SQLException
    {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix( fileType );
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            ImageReader reader = iter.next();
            try
            {
                ImageInputStream stream = new MemoryCacheImageInputStream( blob.getBinaryStream() );
                reader.setInput(stream);
                return reader.getHeight(reader.getMinIndex());
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
            } finally {
                reader.dispose();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Integer getWidth(
            final Blob   blob,
            final String fileType
    ) throws SQLException
    {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix( fileType );
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            ImageReader reader = iter.next();
            try
            {
                ImageInputStream stream = new MemoryCacheImageInputStream( blob.getBinaryStream() );
                reader.setInput(stream);
                return reader.getWidth(reader.getMinIndex());
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
            } finally {
                reader.dispose();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Testing**:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MockBlob implements Blob {
    private final File file;

    public MockBlob(
            final File file
    )
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public long length() throws SQLException {
        return file.length();
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getBinaryStream() throws SQLException {
        try
        {
            return new FileInputStream( this.file );
        }
        catch( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            throw new SQLException( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    @Override public byte[] getBytes(long pos, int length) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
    @Override public long position(byte[] pattern, long start) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
    @Override public long position(Blob pattern, long start) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
    @Override public int setBytes(long pos, byte[] bytes) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");  }
    @Override public int setBytes(long pos, byte[] bytes, int offset, int len) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");  }
    @Override public OutputStream setBinaryStream(long pos) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");  }
    @Override public void truncate(long len) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
    @Override public void free() throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
    @Override public InputStream getBinaryStream(long pos, long length) throws SQLException { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
}
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ImageTest {
    public static void main(
            final String[] args
    ) throws SQLException
    {
        File file = new File( "/path/to/test.png" );
        Blob blob = new MockBlob( file );
        System.out.println(
                "height: "
                + ImageMetaDataReader.getHeight( blob, "png" )
        );
        System.out.println(
                "width: "
                + ImageMetaDataReader.getWidth( blob, "png" )
        );
    }
}
```

**SQL**:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "ImageMetaDataReader" AS
<the java code from above>
/

CREATE FUNCTION getImageHeight(
  file     IN BLOB,
  fileType IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'ImageMetaDataReader.getHeight( java.sql.Blob, String) return Integer';
/

CREATE FUNCTION getImageWidth(
  file     IN BLOB,
  fileType IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'ImageMetaDataReader.getWidth( java.sql.Blob, String) return Integer';
/
```

*(The code is untested in an Oracle database as I don't have an instance to hand at the moment.)*

Comment: Thank you so much MT0, I really appreciate your very good and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Updated with some sample code - its not tested in a database yet but hopefully it will work (or at least give you an idea of a direction to go).

Answer (score 2):

@MT0's answer is the way to go assuming this is a process that needs to work going forward.

Assuming you're not yet on 19.1 and if this is just an ad hoc/ short term requirement, you can [create an `ORDImage` from the `BLOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/aivug/oracle-multimedia-ORDImage-object-type.html#GUID-D949856C-F517-4ACD-95AD-5C29BA7C395D).  Assuming that the image is in one of the file types that `ORDImage` understands (which is, realistically, going to include basically anything that a normal user would be uploading), the constructor can parse the image and extract properties like the height and width that you can then query.  It also provides a variety of methods to manipulate the image (scaling/ rotating/ etc.)

Unfortunately, `ORDImage` has been deprecated in Oracle 18 and I believe it has been removed in Oracle 19 so it's not something that you'd want to use any longer for writing code that you're going to be relying on permanently.  If you're just trying to get an ad hoc report or make a short term data fix, though, it's probably easier than finding, loading, and using a Java image processing library.

Comment: yes Justin as you mentioned I'm not on 19.1(but 12.1.0.2). I really appreciate your comprehensive answer that I'll try firstly.